# GitLab pipeline Junit not recognize my test

Tags: unit-testing, gitlab, pipeline

I gave the path of my tests and the path of the junit file complete and accurate, and the tests were compiled correctly, but the result shows that no tests were found. where is the problem from?

`yml code:`

```
image: openjdk:21

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - javac -d src/src/ca/uqam/info/mgl7460/boutique/bin src/src/ca/uqam/info/mgl7460/boutique/domain/*.java src/src/ca/uqam/info/mgl7460/boutique/implementation/*.java

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - java -jar lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.0.jar -cp src/src/ca/uqam/info/mgl7460/boutique/bin/ --scan-class-path




deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Coming Soon"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwkxy.png)

I tried many codes and I think my codes are correct, but one part of the routing has a problem